# springframework version supported by spring boot 2.7.4 and 2.7.3 version?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, frameworks, version

Which springframework version is supported by spring boot 2.7.4 and 2.7.3 version .

I want latest stable version of spring boot and spring framework.

Comment: Please help me with the framework version under 2.7.4 / 2.7.3 spring boot version

Comment: If my answer helps request you to please accept the answer so that it help others as well

Answer (score 4):

1. Spring Boot 2.7.3 -> Spring Framework 5.3.22
2. Spring Boot 2.7.4 -> Spring Framework 5.3.23

**How to find out the Spring Framework version?**

Go to your project root where pom.xml is present and run this command

`mvn dependency:tree | grep org.springframework:`

*Snapshot of java application running with Spring Boot 2.7.3*

[image]

Comment: Maybe add some more context to your answer. Without more details all this answer does is create more questions. What do you think?

Comment: @treckstar - Yes, you are right. I have added more details to it.